# What Do You Do When You Get Stuck?

Tags: discussion

I'm curious to learn what people do when they don't find a solution to a difficult coding problem on Stack Overflow.

Say you post a question, but it gets buried before a helpful answer is provided.

What do you do? Re-post the question from a different angle? Keep trying until you figure it out? Edit your question? Wait and post a bounty on the question?

Comment: You could keep researching, and editing you question with anything significant you find.

Comment: Never give up!  Just try and look at the problem from a different angle.  I normally get a glass of water and then go for a walk to clear my mind.

Comment: *"'m curious to learn what people do when they don't find a solution to a difficult coding problem on Stack Overflow"* Keep searching, because the answer is somewhere. Nowadays you need to either be very special, or working with cutting edge technology before chance and statistics will allow you to be the one to ask something new.

Comment: SO questions have a tendency to not get buried, thanks to very tight controls by the community and the moderators.  If something is a duplicate, it gets marked as such and tossed.  As Gimby stated, unless you are doing something very unusual, obscure, or new, chances are it's been covered.  Asking a question at SO should be a last resort, not a first one.

Comment: Anecdotal evidence: I [posted a question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/113404/91835) on Code Review a while back, and it received a single upvote before disappearing from notice. It was important for me to get this particular question answered, so I added a bounty after a week of no question activity. Within a few hours after adding the bounty, the question garnered an additional 6 upvotes and an excellent answer. TL;DR: The bounty system works quite well, provided the question is of decent quality.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The first thing you do, as a productive developer, is try and figure out the answer for yourself. You do some research online, using Google and/or Stack Overflow, as well as by consulting the applicable documentation. You try a few things that you can think of to see if they work, and then you iterate through tricks that you already know about, trying to make headway a little bit at a time.

If you still cannot solve the problem, then you ask a question on Stack Overflow. Stay engaged with the question, responding to comments asking for additional information and making suggestions. If you're lucky, one of those comments will jog your memory and get you thinking down the right path. You might even end up solving the problem yourself, allowing you to post your own answer.

Otherwise, you'll have to wait until someone comes along that can answer your question. You can improve your odds by asking a quality question, well-titled and appropriately tagged, complete with [sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), a thorough description of what you are seeking to accomplish, and, if applicable, a summary of what you've already tried.

It may take a while to get a good answer. Stack Overflow isn't a consulting service. You don't wait until the last minute, post a frantic question, and get an immediate answer. If you are getting absolutely no attention, then consider that your question might be the problem. Often, what you think is clear and answerable is only that way because of all the time you've invested in the problem. You know what's in your head, but others don't. Keep editing and improving the question as you go, seeking to clarify, and hopefully garnering more attention along the way.

If several days pass and you still get no bites on your question, then you can consider offering a bounty. Again, some critical perspective is required: is your question failing to get attention because there really isn't enough incentive for people to answer it? Or is it failing to get attention because it has some kind of problem or lack of clarity that makes it difficult/impossible for people to answer? I can't speak for others; I think bounties *do* motivate a lot of people, but they don't motivate me. I look for *interesting* questions to answer (where I stand to learn something from the time I invest), not those that I stand to gain a lot of rep from. I have enough magical Internet points, I don't really need any more. Still, a bounty can help your question stand out from a long list of crappy questions, in case an expert missed it when perusing their favorite tags.

Another thing that productive programmers *often* do is to move on to something else, letting their subconscious brain mull over the problem for a couple of days. When you come back to it later, you will have a fresh perspective and, if you're lucky, you'll have some new ideas from "sleeping on it." This is yet another good reason not to wait until the last minute or to push against a hard deadline. If you absolutely must ship (and everyone knows "real artists ship"), then change course, hack it, or cut the feature—put a proper solution on the schedule for the next release. Hopefully, by that time, you'll get some attention on your Stack Overflow question. Or at least you'll be well-rested enough to think of a solution yourself.

Related to this is [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). Sit down and try to explain your problem—either to a coworker or to a rubber duck. This forces you to evaluate the problem from a different perspective, and often to think more clearly. We often get anecdotal reports from people that the mere act of composing a high-quality question for submission to Stack Overflow will have the same effect as rubber duck debugging. Or, if you're even luckier, you'll find a similar question that covers the same ground as yours and either contains an answer or points you in the right place.

[image: A rubber duck. What else?]